# Where to study type theory?

Tags: soft-question, education, type-theory

I want to learn more about (homotopy) type theory, constructive mathematics and univalent foundations. To my knowledge, there are only few faculties with large type theory groups. In Europe, most of the research seems to be located in Scandinavia and the Netherlands (e.g. Gothenburg and Nijmegen).

Where are the geographic hot spots of academic research in type theory, from a mathematical or computer science perspective?